# How to get a java.io.File from R.raw resource

Tags: android, kotlin

I added a raw resource to my Android Studio project:

Then I need to get a `java.io.File` instance pointing to it.

I have tried three things, but file cannot be found and `File.exists()` is equal false:

```
// Option 1:
//
//     com.example.myapp:raw/plano_metrobus
//
val fileName = resources.getResourceName(R.raw.plano_metrobus)
Log.w("xxx", fileName)
Log.w("xxx", File(fileName).exists().toString())

// Option 2
//
//     android.resource://com.example.myapp:raw/plano_metrobus
//
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + fileName)
Log.w("xxx", uri.toString())
Log.w("xxx", File(uri.toString()).exists().toString())

// Option 3
//
//     android.resource://com.example.myapp/2131427328
//
val uri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.plano_metrobus)
Log.w("xxx", uri2.toString())
Log.w("xxx", File(uri2.toString()).exists().toString())
```

What is the right way to create a `File` object?

Answer (score 2):

> Then I need to get a java.io.File instance pointing to it.

That is not directly possible. It is a file on your development machine. It is not a standalone file on the device — it is merely an entry in the APK file on the device.

> What is the right way to get a File object?

Ideally, you don't. You cannot modify the resource, and hopefully whatever that you are using that accepts a `File` can also accept an `InputStream`. If so, [use `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)), and you get one of those by calling `getResources()` on a `Context` (e.g., `Activity`, `Service`).

If you are using some third-party library that was poorly written and requires a file, you would need to use that `openRawResource()` approach, then copy the bytes from that `InputStream` to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). You can then use the resulting file.

Comment: I am using [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html), and I do not see an alternative. I'll try the option of copying the stream.

Comment: To use with PdfRenderer.

Comment: "It is a file on your development machine" that doesn't sound right. `raw` resources are in the apk

Comment: @njzk2: Yes, and the APK is a ZIP file. Resources are not unpacked from that ZIP file. Hence, it is a file on the development machine, but it is not a file on the device.

Comment: ok, I get what you mean. In your answer it sounds a bit like you are saying that the file is not present _at all_ on the device, but stays on the dev machine.

Comment: @kiewic: There is another flavor of `openRawResource()` that returns an `AssetFileDescriptor`. That has [a `getParcelFileDescriptor()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#getParcelFileDescriptor()) to get a `ParcelFileDescriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous advice, I ended up using `Context.getCacheDir()` to create a uncompressed version of the file, and then been able to use it with `PdfRenderer`. Here is the solution:

```
val FILENAME = "FileName.pdf"
val file = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, FILENAME)
if (!file.exists()) {
    val input = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.plano_metrobus)
    val output = FileOutputStream(file)

    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    while (true) {
        val size = input.read(buffer)
        if (size == -1) {
            break;
        }
        output.write(buffer, 0, size)
    }

    input.close()
    output.close()
}

val fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
val renderer = PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
```